# i downloaded a csv file, but data is not separated by commas

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I downloaded a dataset from kaggle.
kaggle data:
[image: kaggle data]

but all the data is in one column in excel.
data in excel:
[image: data in excel]

I need this data for my project. how can I get this data separated?

Comment: When you open the file in a basic text editor, like Notepad, do you see commas or other delimiters? Have you retrieved a new copy of the data to see if there was an error in the original report?

Comment: Looks like the file is already tab separated, which is what Excel uses internally when you copy and paste. So the easiest is to just open it in the default Notepad app, select all, copy and then paste in Excel

Answer (score 4):

Your Data is not CSV (Comma Separated Values) rather it is TSV (Tab Separated Values) that is why you see everything in 1 Column.

There are various ways to handle TSV in MS Excel , including while loading or after loading.
Here , I will give a Solution based on your Screen Shot.

Go to your WorkSheet & Select Column A.  Select "Data" on the Menu & then "Text to Columns"

[image: Data + Text to Columns]

Then Choose "Delimited" & then Select Delimiter "Tab".

Make suitable changes to the Column types , then finally click "finish".

Now you should have got the multiple Columns you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Save the file in CSV UTF-8 format in Excel-Save As.
[image]

Comment: This may not work , because MS Excel is Currently seeing a Single column & it will save that Single column in "save as" & when the new Document gets reopened , it will still have that Single Column.